# FTP for Verio Starter Pack

Tags: ftp

Anyone have any idea how to connect to their FTP server? I am using Domain Name + Starter pack (the one that comes free with the domain name registration). I have tried using Microsoft Expression Web and IE8, both can't connect to the port 21.

Comment: @Marc hmm... I tried, same error message (no service on port 21). Tried changing to port 22, no go as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this somewhere on the documentation:
http://www.verio.com/support/documents/view_article.cfm?doc_id=4055

No FTP for shared IP product. Why would they give free web space then? :(